# Subscribing to custom event channel with enriched fields

Tags: custom, empapi

Using LWC I'm trying to subscribe to a custom event channel. Unfortunately, I'm getting the "The channel specified is not valid" error.
I created a custom event channel and event channel member using Postman, as suggested in the Trailhead using the following requests:

```
  "FullName": "SalesEvents__chn",
  "Metadata": {
    "channelType": "data",
    "label": "Custom Channel for Sales App"
  }
}
```

```
  "FullName": "SalesEvents_AccountChangeEvent",
  "Metadata": {
    "enrichedFields": [
      {
        "name": "Industry"
      },
      {
        "name": "BillingAddress"
      }
    ],
    "eventChannel": "SalesEvents__chn",
    "selectedEntity": "AccountChangeEvent"
  }
}
```

I have the Account object selected in the Change Data Capture tab in org Settings. Subscriptions are working well for basic CDC for both standard and custom objects. Below is my LWC:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe } from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class ChangeDataCaptureTestComponent extends LightningElement {
  taskChannelName = '/data/task__ChangeEvent'; // custom obj, basic channel -> working
  accChannelName = '/data/AccountChangeEvent'; // standard obj, basic channel -> working
  customChannelName = '/data/SalesEvents__chn'; // custom event channel -> throws an error
  taskSubscription = {};
  accSubscription = {};
  customSubscription = {};

  connectedCallback() {
    this.registerSubscribe();
  }

  // Called by connectedCallback()
  registerSubscribe() {
    const changeEventCallback = (changeEvent) => {
      this.processChangeEvent(changeEvent);
    };

    // Sets up subscription and callback for change events
    subscribe(this.taskChannelName, -1, changeEventCallback).then(
      (subscription) => {
        this.taskSubscription = subscription;
        console.log(' taskChannel subscribed ✨', subscription.channel);
      }
    );
    subscribe(this.accChannelName, -1, changeEventCallback).then(
      (subscription) => {
        this.accSubscription = subscription;
        console.log(' accChannel subscribed ✨', subscription.channel);
      }
    );
    subscribe(this.customChannelName, -1, changeEventCallback).then(
      (subscription) => {
        this.customSubscription = subscription;
        console.log(' customChannel subscribed ✨', subscription.channel);
      }
    );
  }

  // Called by registerSubscribe()
  processChangeEvent(changeEvent) {
    try {
      const recordIds = changeEvent.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.recordIds;
      console.log(recordIds);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was the missing namespace!